# Is it possible to have an unanswered question re-opened, so I can answer it?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59373280/is-it-possible-to-color-java-output-in-terminal-using-rgb-or-hex-colors) was closed because it was marked as a duplicate of similar questions. However, I don't feel that it actually was a duplicate. This author was specifically asking about using precise RBG colors, not the standard 4-bit color pallet. He also explicitly references the ANSI escape color codes, as being insufficient, because the color pallet is too small. However, his question was marked as a duplicate of other answers explaining how to use the limited 4-bit color pallet.

I have composed a more specific answer which speaks to his precise needs, and explains how to use newer revisions of the ANSI standard, to explicitly use 24-bit "true color" RGB ANSI escape codes. And I originally found his question, because I had the same issue and the existing answers suggesting the 4-bit color pallet were insufficient.

Is it possible to have this question re-opened so that I can answer it?

Comment: It was already reopened 40ish minutes before you posted this

Comment: Oh, I initially posted this question in the wrong channel and then had to wait 40 minutes to post again. I guess someone saw the initial posting and reopened it. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't apply to questions with weak duplicates, and that appears to have been the case here, but for those that are justified closures, the recommended course of action is to add an answer to the duplicate..